# Question about a point in Srednicki's QFT book

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, wavefunction, klein-gordon-equation, born-rule

On page 6, Sredniciki says (taking into account the erratum), that the "simplest possibility is for Alice and Bob to agree on the value of the wave function at a particular space-time point". This feels "too strong" a requirement on the wave function $\psi$. I would have "naturally" asked only for *measurements*, i.e. $|\psi|^2$, to be the same in different coordinate systems. $\psi$ is not observed directly, only $|\psi|^2$ is. Similarly, I would not require 1.20 and 1.21 (the Klein-Gordon equation in the 2 coordinate systems) be the same, since these equations deal with $\psi$, but what we want is the measurements to agree. What happens if we require $|\psi|^2$ to agree?

Comment: It's indeed too strong, and in fact in Galilean relativity it's false! However, the Klein-Gordan equation should properly be interpreted as one for a classical field, not a wavefunction of a quantum particle, so there's no issue in that case.

Comment: If you are interpreting $\psi$ as a wave-function, then the physical thing is not $|\psi|^2$ but $\psi$, up to a _constant_ phase. This means that Alice and Bob should agree in the sense that Alice might have $\psi$ but Bob might have $e^{i\phi}\psi$, with constant $\phi$. I don't think it is very useful to think about this in the context of K-G equation, but in general context of states it leads to the statement that Hilbert space is not, generally speaking, a representation of the symmetry group, but rather a _projective_ representation.

Comment: Note that saying that only $|\psi|^2$ is observable is like saying that you can only observe functions of position of the particle. This is not true, you can also observe functions of momentum.

Answer (score 1):

The requirement for "physics to look the same" in different coordinate systems is related to the reasoning that coordinates are artefacts of the human mind and therefore the form of the physical laws should be independent from them. That is why the physical laws are written in tensorial formalism.

In any case, if $\psi$ is a scalar, being a scalar an invariant by definition, you expect $\psi(x) = \bar \psi(\bar x)$, where $x$ and $\bar x$ are two different coordinate systems.

As for the $\vert \psi \vert^2$ requirement, it is not applicable. Reason is that Klein-Gordon equation obeys relativity, but not quantum mechanics. The norm of a state, that is $\vert \psi \vert^2$, is in general time dependent, so the probability is not conserved.